# How to solve the irrational inequality?

Tags: problem-solving

Solve the inequality
$$\dfrac{2x^4+2x^2}{\sqrt{x+1}}+(x+2)\sqrt{x+1}>x ^3 + 2x^2 + 5x.$$
I tried. By putting $t = \sqrt{x+1}$, we have
$$2t^8-t^7-8t^6+t^5+15t^4-4t^3-11t^2+4t+4>0.$$
Using Maple, I got
$$(2t^2-t-2)(t^2-t-1)(t^4+t^3-t^2-t+2)>0.$$
How to solve the given inequality with another way?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking for a completely different method, or don't mind continuing what you have.

Answer (score 1):

[image: a picture]

Try to make sure the coefficient of the largest degree of $t$ is positive.

Then, solve all the roots of the polynomial $P(t)=0$.

Then draw a picture as above.

Draw a axis.

Then draw a thread goes through the line from the roots. If there is multiple root, goes through the line and goes back. **Right to left. Rightmost must be above the axis.**

The positive intervals are above the axis.

Comment: Of course, you must make sure that $t \ge 0$.

Comment: Viva China ;-) +1

Comment: @eccstartup Good answer! but note that more precisely we should consider $t>0$ Furthermore for $t=0$ we have $P(0)=4$ hence the leftmost must be above the axis. If you draw the graph for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ the leftmost must be above the axis too because the graph behave like $2t^8$ as $t\to\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You also want the condition that $ t \geq 0$.

**Hint:** The quartic polynomial $t^4 + t^3 - t^2 - t + 2 = (t^2 + 0.5 t -1)^2 + 0.75t^2 + 1$ is always positive for all real $t$.

You can continue from what you have (assuming your calculations are correct).

---

I'm not sure if this helps, but your inequality can be simplified to

$$ (x^2-x+2)(2x^2+2x+1) > x(x^2+2x+5) \sqrt{x+1}$$