# How to solve inequalities with one variable by number line

Tags: inequality

I can solve simple type of inequalities by number line . For example, if I want to solve $x>6$ by number line , then I have to plot this solution into number line which is described in the following image .

[image]

How can  I solve inequalities with one variable by number line ? Suppose that , I have the following inequalities:

$$x^2-5x+6<0$$

Remember I have to solve this inequality by number line . Suppose , I have applied the following procedure to solve this :

> 1. the solution to the above inequality is $2<x<3$
> 2. Then I have plotted the solution $2<x<3$ in number line  .

This solution is not acceptable because I have to solve the above inequality by number line. Can you guys plz help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: I have no idea what "solving by number line" would actually mean. I would have done the same as you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441017/how-to-solve-the-irrational-inequality/441024#441024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with I would talk to the teacher, asking why certain solutions are not accepted.

For the inequality 
$$x^2-5x+6 <0\tag{1}$$
it is easier to factorise $x^2-5x+6$ first. That is we look for two numbers $A$ and $B$ such that $x^2-5x+6=A\cdot B$, because solving 
$$A\cdot B <0\tag{2}$$ 
is easy: (2) can only happen when both $A<0$ and $B>0$, or both $A>0$ and $B<0$.

Now, to factorise $x^2-5x+6$ we first complete the square
\begin{eqnarray}x^2-5x+6& =& \left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^2 -\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2+6\\
&=& \left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^2 -\frac{25}{4}+6\\
&=& \left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^2 -\frac{25}{4}+\frac{6\cdot4}{4}\\
&=& \left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^2 -\frac{25}{4}+\frac{24}{4}
&=& \left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^2 -\frac{1}{4}
\end{eqnarray}
and use the conjugation rule $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$, so that 
\begin{eqnarray}
x^2-5x+6 &=& \left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^2 -\frac{1}{4} \\&=& \left(x - \frac{5}{2} +\frac12\right)\left(x - \frac{5}{2} -\frac12\right)\\
&=& \left(x - 2\right)\left(x - 3\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Now, for (1) we get the inequalities (or rather system of inequalities)
$$\left(x - 2\right)<0 \text{ and }\left(x - 3\right)>0\tag{3}$$
and 
$$\left(x - 2\right)>0 \text{ and }\left(x - 3\right)<0\tag{4}$$
which are linear and can be "solved using number line" (or by the algebraic method of adding a number to both sides of the inequalities). 
Note that (3) has no solution, while (4) is the line segment you found.